# Global Variable Not Passing To Next Package

Tags: mysql, go

As golang does not support circular dependencies, and I am only just starting in golang. I've run into a little wall with my connection variable, I am using the gorm driver, and MySQL as my database engine.

And I'm trying to pass on the connection variable to the next function my program calls, which is in another file.
**AchFactory.go**

```
fmt.Println(">Loading Achievements")
Start.DB.HasTable("achievements")
Start.DB.Select("id", "group_name", "category", "level", "reward_pixels", "reward_points", "progress_needed", "game_id").Find("achievements")
fmt.Println(">Found Schema")
```

**Start.go**

```
var DB *gorm.DB

func Initi() {
    fmt.Println("Initating!")
    Connect()
}

func Connect() {
    var err error
    DB, err = gorm.Open("mysql", config.MYSQL_USER+":"+config.MYSQL_PASS+"@/"+config.MYSQL_DB+"?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
        DB.Close()
    }
    fmt.Println(">Connection Succesful")
    fmt.Println(">Test Query Starting")
    TestQ()
}

func TestQ() {
    DB.HasTable("tests")
    fmt.Println(">Query Succesful!")
    AchManager.GetAch()
}
```

Would just like to know what i've done wrong so i can prevent this error in the future. Thank you :)

Comment: Where are you trying to pass the connection to `AchFactory.go`?

Comment: if **Start.go** under package _x_ for example, and you want to call variable _DB_ to another package, you should add  package name then dot before variable name `x.DB`.

[note](https://blog.golang.org/package-names): _Good package names are short and clear. They are lower case, with no under_scores or mixedCaps._

Comment: Please include the import statements from both *Start.go* and *AchFactory.go*. Also you mentioned an error you want to prevent but you didn't include the actual error message, it is easier for us to help you if we know the exact error you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

If your `AchFactory.go` file is in the same package as your `Start.go` file you don't need to prefix `DB` with anything, since both files live in the same package they both share the variables defined at the package level.

For example:

```
.
└── foo
    ├── AchFactory.go
    └── Start.go
```

*Start.go*

```
package foo

// ...

var DB *gorm.DB

// ...
```

*AchFactory.go*

```
package foo

func F() {
    fmt.Println(">Loading Achievements")
    DB.HasTable("achievements")
    DB.Select("id", "group_name", "category", "level", "reward_pixels", "reward_points", "progress_needed", "game_id").Find("achievements")
    fmt.Println(">Found Schema")
}
```

---

If, on the other hand, `AchFactory.go` lives in a different package than `Start.go` then the `AchFactory.go` file needs to `import` the package that contains the `Start.go` file, and then to access the exported members of the imported pacakge you prefix them with the name of the package and join the two with a dot; e.g. `packagename.Membername`.

For example:

```
.
├── foo
│   └── Start.go
└── bar
    └── AchFactory.go
```

*Start.go*

```
package foo

// ...

var DB *gorm.DB

// ...
```

*AchFactory.go*

```
package bar

import (
    "fmt"
    "path/to/foo"
)

func F() {
    fmt.Println(">Loading Achievements")
    foo.DB.HasTable("achievements")
    foo.DB.Select("id", "group_name", "category", "level", "reward_pixels", "reward_points", "progress_needed", "game_id").Find("achievements")
    fmt.Println(">Found Schema")
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for you're help, its fixed :)